what is a general region in the ocean called?
Is there a general term for a region in the ocean like the Bermuda Triangle? Like, on land, we call a stretch of land or strip of land. Is a stretch of water correct?
Edit: Just to clarify: I am looking for a term that can refer to any small part of the larger ocean whether it has geographical distinctions(such as being close to or surrounded by land) or not.

Is a stretch of water correct? Yes, it is.

@WeatherVane So, stretch of water would sound normal in a sentence? For eg. This is the most treacherous stretch of water this side of the ocean.

Other terms such as gulf, bay, bight, straight, sound, channel etc. and have specific meanings, but stretch can be used in the same way as for land.

It is unclear whether the question is seeking a term that can be applied to any part of an ocean, even if its boundaries are entirely arbitrary, or a term for a body of water that seems intuitively distinct from the rest of the relevant ocean, because of its relationship to the surrounding geographic formations. If the former, then there is probably no term for it, other than something like body of water, but if the latter, the term is sea.

Indeed. The Sargasso Sea comes to mind.

Sea or gulf for oceanic regions partially surrounded by land, otherwise, there's no special term I know of for oceanic regions. That said, technically the five "oceans" of the world are giant regions of the same global body of water.
